# Removing an element by ID (jointJS)

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I noticed that JointJS links can be removed by hovering over them and clicking the big red X that appears.  But I was wondering if it is possible remove an element once it has been created, **without knowing** the variable name.

```
onCreateButtonClick(function(){
  var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
    position: { x: 100, y: 30 },
    size: { width: 100, height: 30 }
  });
  graph.addCell([rect]);
});

onRemoveButtonClick(function(){
   //removeRectangle here?
});
```

My question is: can I remove this rectangle in the second function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Removing elements by ID can simply be done as: `graph.getCell(cellID).remove()`. In your `onRemoveButonClick()`, you have to somehow know which element you want to remove. This depends on you application UI but you can, for example, do something like:

```
var selected;

paper.on('cell:pointerdown', function(cellView) {
    selected = cellView.model;
});

onRemoveButtonClick(function() { 
    if (selected) selected.remove(); 
});
```

Comment: graph.getCell(cellID).remove() does not remove a cell if the cell has children. I get this exception when I try to remove a cell that has children 
 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unembed' of undefined

How to delete all the cells of a graph, embedded and un-embedded?

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the removal of an element by single clicking the element , using the cellView arguement directly.

```
paper.on('cell:pointerclick', function(cellView, evt, x, y) {
    cellView.remove();
});
```

Comment: How to save it to json dynamically?

Comment: Do you mean to ask how to update the json for removed element ? Are you maintaining the json for paper manually ?

Comment: Yes, when ever i change or remove element i want to save it to JSON ans send to the server